# Is there a pipe-like .NET Stream class that doesn't use OS pipes?

Tags: c#, .net, mono

Using C#/.NET (Xamarin/Mono, really).

I have a class with a method (A) that accepts a stream that it writes to,
and I have another class with a method (B) that accepts a stream to read from.

I want to have a stream that is passed to both (A) and (B), such that when
(A) writes to the stream, that data can be read by (B).

Is there already such a beast that doesn't using OS pipes?

Comment: `System.Collections.Concurrent.BlockingCollection` ?

Comment: See this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12328245/517852)

Comment: +1 for use of the word 'beast'

Comment: Possibly a NetworkStream

Comment: Looks like I need a Socket to use NetworkStream.

Answer (score 1):

i would use [BlockingCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). For example

```
BlockingCollection<int> bc = new BlockingCollection<int>();
Task.Run(() => new Reader(bc).DoWork());
Task.Run(() => new Writer(bc).DoWork());
```

---

```
public class Reader
{
    BlockingCollection<int> _Pipe = null;
    public Reader(BlockingCollection<int> pipe)
    {
        _Pipe = pipe;
    }

    public void DoWork()
    {
        foreach(var i in _Pipe.GetConsumingEnumerable())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("END");
    }
}

public class Writer
{
    BlockingCollection<int> _Pipe = null;
    public Writer(BlockingCollection<int> pipe)
    {
        _Pipe = pipe;
    }

    public void DoWork()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            _Pipe.Add(i);
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
        _Pipe.CompleteAdding();
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like the right semantics, but I'm looking for a derivative of Stream so that I can just plug it in. This is like going to Home Depot and finding that nobody has ever manufactured a double-ended female coupling!

Comment: Sorry no built-in way for `so that you can just plug it in`. You have to show some effort to get it. I am too lazy to write it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can create one around a `MemoryStream`, let's call it a `ConcurrentMemoryStream`.

You will need to make sure all the reads and writes are synchronized. You will also need to keep two pointers - one for reading and the other for writing, and seek to the proper place before a read or write operation.

Oh, and see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12328307/871910, as @mike z pointed out in a comment.

Comment: MemoryStream doesn't have one position for read and one for write.  `ms.WriteByte(1); ms.WriteByte(2); var b1 = m.ReadByte();` *b1* will be -1.

Comment: Hmmm, right. So the ConcurrentMemoryStream will have to keep two positions, and seek every read and write. Not a major issue.

Comment: Except that isn't concurrent _at all_.